# Uniform access of Google App Engine access to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-iam

I am trying to change access to Google Cloud Storage buckets from App Engine.  The buckets contains image file (PNGs).  The app generates web pages that show various images from the buckets.

With the default fine grained access it works.  This has been the way the app has always been configured.

In trying to switch to uniform access, the images no longer appear on the web pages.  I've added the GAE service account with Storage Object Viewer.  Doesn't work.  I've even added allUsers with Storage Object Viewer and that doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you enable uniform bucket-level access on an existing bucket, you should ensure that users and services that previously relied on ACLs for access have their permissions migrated to IAM. This section outlines some steps you should take when migrating a bucket to uniform bucket-level access. Note that since ACLs and IAM are [synchronized for bucket permissions,](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam#acls) your considerations focus specifically on access to objects within your bucket and not on access to the bucket.

You may want to give a try to this [document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uniform-bucket-level-access) that describe the behavior expected when you enable or use the uniform access.

Comment: Let me ask this more as a use case question.

This is basically a web based app and the images must appear in a web page, does it make sense to use any type of uniform access policy that is not public access? 

We would like to prevent people from guessing the URLs of the pages (in GCS) and displaying random images.  That is why we considered a non-public access policy.  

Maybe a better way to do this is to make all images public and use signed URLs.  The images would still be public but it would be much more difficult to guess a URL of any image.